# Show div tag when button is clicked with $emit and $on

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two controllers ParentController and ChildController. What i want to achieve is when button from ChildController is clicked to emit event and listen for that event in ParentController and when button is clicked to show iframe in div tag. You can find my code below.

**ParentController**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {   

}]);
```

*ChildController**

```
myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}]);
```

**View for ParentController**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  <div class="module-content">
     <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div content-body>
      <div ng-show="$on('showiframe')">
         <iframe ng-src={{url}} frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

**View for ChildController**
      
        
           Show IFrame

So can i do something like this, listen for event in div tag in ng-show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ChildController, $emit an event on your button click. $emit will dispatch the event upwards through the scope hierarchy.

Child view :

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showIframe()">Show iframe</button>
```

Child controller :

```
myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showIframe = function () {
        $scope.$emit('showiframe');
    }
}]);
```

In your parent controller, create a listener on 'showIframe' event.

Parent view :

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  <div class="module-content">
     <h3>Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div content-body>
      <div ng-show="showIframe">
         <iframe ng-src={{url}} frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Parent controller :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     // Iframe is not showed initially     
     $scope.showIframe = false;   

     $scope.$on('showIframe', function() {
          $scope.showIframe = true;
     });
}]);
```

Edit :

Regarding your fiddle, for example, you can watch the inputText model and emit the events :

```
$scope.$watch('inputText', function () {
        $scope.$emit('send-date', $scope.date);
        $scope.$emit('send-input', $scope.inputText);
});
```

This will emit the events each time the inputText models changes.

Comment: Thanks @Komo. Can you please look at these fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bF9Pq/695/ for other question? I have input text and input date in ChildController. What I want to achieve is to take values from this inputs in ChildController and pass them to ParentController, which is listening for these values. Also for date input i want to set default value to be Date.now() and if i choose other date from datepicker i want to send that value to ParentController.

Comment: In your fiddle, you're emitting the send-date and send-input events on controller init once.
You need an action (button click for example) (or a $watch) where you trigger the $emit. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much my man!!!! So now i am little confused why i cant take the value for $scope.startDate and $scope.getInputText out of this two functions in MainController... I am defining them at beginning $scope.startDate = null;  $scope.getInputText = null; and then assign value at functions for $on ?

Comment: What do you mean by no taking the value ?
Try to type something in the input : http://jsfiddle.net/bF9Pq/696/

Comment: No no this is working with watch. I was saying that as you can see i have two console.log($scope.startDate) and console.log($scope.getInputText); that are out of functions where i am listening. So i want to take those values in functions for example in some other function in MainController.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bF9Pq/697/ ?
You have access to theses $scope variable once you have emitted the events